# How do I swap two elements in a LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, swap

How do you swap two elements in `LinkedList` in Java?
Suppose:

```
LinkedList<Integer> ttt = new LinkedList<Integer>();
ttt.add(1);
ttt.add(2);
ttt.add(4);
// etc........
```

How to swap 2 and 3?

Comment: Rosy, have you made any effort to solve this yourself?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and especially read [ask]. You are expected to attempt a solution on your own and ask if you encounter problems.  SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Do you mean LinkedList?

Comment: Ya I had tried it on my own.I did my creating a new class node and using prev and next using the concept of LInkedlist head and all.But I was told to do it in a more simpler way which I couldnot do.

Comment: In LInkedlist you cannot directly as we used to do in array.So ??

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkedList` is just the implementation of the `List` abstract data type (ADT), and the List ADT has all the same methods regardless of whether the implementation is a `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`.

So you would swap 2 and 3 in the `LinkedList` the same way you would swap 2 and 3 in an `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> listOfNumbers = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6));
int twoIndex = listOfNumbers.indexOf(2);
int threeIndex = listOfNumbers.indexOf(3);
listOfNumbers.set(twoIndex, 3);
listOfNumbers.set(threeIndex, 2);
```